# How to create popup alert with several copy to clipboard buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this popup window and was wondering how I can create it with js. Can anybody give me a hint? Could not find a comparable solution here on stack...

[image]

Comment: You could look at using Bootstrap modals for the popup with HTML/Jquery to handle the click events from the buttons; there are plenty of examples as to how to copy to the clipboard. However, this is very broad for an SO question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, blame on me - am a noob and always try my best. It‘s not my intention to waste your time and thank you a lot for helping me. Was always focused on ginding a solution using js alert and didn‘t thought about modals.

Answer (score 1):

For copying to clipboard you can use this code. First you select the element "The text area" then use `select()` function and finally use exec command to copy

```js
function copyLink(id){
  var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
 <textarea id="firstTextArea">www.google.com</textarea>
 <button onclick="copyLink('firstTextArea')">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Thx Andam, but how can I put this in an alert popup?

Comment: @JakobTiebel There are plenty of solutions. You can use jquery ui, bootstrap, and so on just google html modal. I would suggest to use the jquery ui if you are just starting out